# How to get the topic coverage for a document using LDA?

Tags: text-mining, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I have three distributions of topic obtained by Latent Dirichlet allocation:

- **theme_1** = {cat*0.7, dog*0.2, pet*0.1},
- **theme_2** = {salad*0.5, fish*0.3, chicken*0.2},
- **theme_3** = {cuisine*0.4, food*0.3, tomato*0.3},

I need to calculate the coverage of each item in a document having a word count vector for example:

- **d1** = {Dog: 4, Fish: 6, Cooking: 2: Tomato: 0, Chicken: 5, Meal: 2}

to result in a topic vector instead of the word count vector in this way:

- **d1** = {theme_1, theme_2, theme_3}.

I was calculating this way:

- theme_1 in d1 = probability(dog in theme_1) * # Occurrences(dog in d1)

Because only "dog" occurs in the topic "theme_1" and in the document and so on.

Is it the right way to do it? Because I also understand that the coverage of topics in a document must be equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

As there are SO questions and solutions for this problem in both [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875493/lda-with-topicmodels-how-can-i-see-which-topics-different-documents-belong-to) and [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984841/topic-distribution-how-do-we-see-which-document-belong-to-which-topic-after-doi), I assume you came here to ask for the mathematical/algorithmic explanation how these tools generate the per-document topic distributions.

Using Blei's typical nomenclature, we let $\theta_{d,j}$ be the proportion of topic $j$ in document $d$. As we know from Blei, the LDA model is defined as the following joint probability:

$$
p( \overrightarrow{\beta}, \overrightarrow{\theta}, \overrightarrow{z}, \overrightarrow{w} ; \alpha, \eta ) =
\left( \prod_i p( \beta_i | \eta ) \right)
\left(
  \prod_d p( \theta_d | \alpha)
  \prod_n p(z_{d,n} | \theta_d ) p( w_{d,n} | \overrightarrow{\beta}, z_{d,n})
\right)
$$

With $\alpha$ and $\eta$ being the two Dirichlet priors (for documents and topics, respectively).

Therefore, the posterior estimate for a specific topic and document is - e.g., if approximated by [*stochastic* variational inference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.7051.pdf) via (re-) running the inference (algorithm) on the (final) model - essentially:

$$
\theta_{d,j} =
\frac{ C_{d,j} + \alpha_j }
     { \sum_k C_{d,k} + \alpha_k }
$$

Where $C$ is the document-topic assignment (counts) matrix. That is, the raw result of a single [inference step](https://github.com/blei-lab/onlineldavb/blob/master/onlineldavb.py) (also see gensim's [`LdaModel.inference`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/6a289fefd72f038c8cc14826f63624950f5de1f8/gensim/models/ldamodel.py#L401)). Note that due to sampling from the Dirichlet prior during the inference, [your results will vary ever so slightly on each run](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/591). But if your model is good, the variations should be small (so this is a good way to estimate model quality).